# Science fiction novel about misfit children with different powers living in a communal house

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a short novel from the 80s/90s (or possibly earlier). I never read the whole thing, but it starts out with an adult “normal” character drives his car to a remote house where multiple children and teenagers with mental powers (telekinesis, etc) live. As far as I can recall, there are no adults in the house.

The scene I clearly recall occurs shortly after the adult arrives at the house. After a brief tour of the house given by one of the female teenagers, he sits down with her and possibly other characters to have a discussion. They serve him coffee, and he ends up spilling it all over his lap. A young boy in the room uses his powers of telekinesis to lift up the particles of coffee from his clothing and it’s like the spill never happened.

Edit: It’s not More Than Human by Theodore Sturgeon. In the story I’m trying to ID, the main character who went to the house in which the children live was an adult, and had no special powers or status. I think they referred to their powers as “gifts” or “talents.”

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Check out the [suggestions for a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be Theodore Sturgeon's *More Than Human*? The novel was an expansion of the novella ["Baby Is Three"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Is_Three) first published in the October 1952 *Galaxy*.  Sturgeon added two more novellas, "The Fabulous Idiot" and "Morality" to form the novel, [More Than Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Than_Human).  It isn't a perfect match for the details you list, but it seems to be close enough that it might be the source.

Comment: It may well be. I really only recall that specific scene. I’m borrowing it from my local library, and will report back here.

Comment: Well I just finished the book and while it was a fantastic novel, it unfortunately wasn’t the one I recall. Wow, what a story, though! I don’t think the one I recall was on that level of writing.